Improper multiple integral of vector valued function and corresponding Fubini's theorem
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to X$ be an appropriate function where $X$ is a Banach space.
I want to know the definition of the improper Riemann integral
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f,
\end{equation}
and when we can compute it by iterated integral.
I have a book on analysis but it only deals with a case where $X = \mathbb{R}$ and it uses the order of $\mathbb{R}$.

You can define a Lebesgue integral of such $f$. It is known as the Bochner integral. See https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/vecint.pdf I guess that you can prove Fubini's theorem from this integral; the proof should not be too different from the proof when $X = \mathbb{R}$.

@Kakashi Thank you very much!
